# codeigniter-paypal. doesn't redirect to paypal in iframe

Tags: php, codeigniter, iframe, paypal

i'm using codeigniter to integrate paypal digital goods payment. 
After I click on "pay by paypal", it's supposed to ask user do login/signup in paypal **iframe**, but mine will redirect user to sandbox link. after user click on "login", it will popup the iframe.

now it's sth like this:[image]

I want the iframe right after user click on "pay by paypal", like this:
[image]
.. how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is the source of the frame using SSL e.g. HTTPS?  If so including the frame into a non SSL page will not work except in the least secure browsers.  I'm not even sure it would work in a fully SSL setting as it's a perfect way to steal logins etc using JS.

From a customer point of view I'd want to be directed WHOLLY to PayPal as I trust them more than your site.